# How to deserialize part of the View-Model gracefully, not losing previous data-binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

My `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyViewModelType {
    public PlayerElements Player { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

`PlayerElements` contains many bindable properties:

```
public class PlayerElements : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    ObservableCollection<IEntity> Angles { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    ObservableCollection<IBuilding> Castles { get; set; }

    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
}
```

When I deserialize a saved Model, I do something like this:

```
    public MyViewModelType ViewModel { get; set; }

    public LoadPlayerFromDisk(SomeDataModel dm){
        ViewModel.Player = new PlayerElements(vm.PlayerData);
    }
```

The problem is clear: I lose all bindings when I create new `PlayerElements`. My current solution is to clear all lists and add them manually:

```
ViewModel.Player.Angles.Clear();
foreach (var angel in vm.PlayerData.Angles)
    ViewModel.Player.Angles.Add(angel);
```

needless to say - horrible solution...

Another option I thought of, would be to copy all events handlers to the new object using a large dose of reflection. It is the same type of bad solution: I need to walk the whole tree (property of `ObservableCollection<T>`, each item implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and can have more children of `ObservableCollection<T>` type, and so on...)

So how can I deserialize the view-model gracefully, without losing all binding?

Comment: Odd, you know what INotifyPropertyChanged is, why didn't you implement it in your VM?

Comment: @Will, I implemented it, I removed a whole lot of code for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason you should lose your bindings, unless you are not raising the necessary property change notifications for the binding engine to see your property assignments.  From the code you pasted, this seems to be the case.

Your property setters need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event exposed by `INotifyPropertyChanged`, e.g.:

```
public class MyViewModelType : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private PlayerElements _player;

    public PlayerElements Player {
        get { return _player; }
        set { 
            _player = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Player");
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
    }
}
```

When the binding receives the notification that `Player` has changed, it will automatically unsubscribe from notifications of subproperties that had bindings and subscribe to the subproperties of the new `Player`.  You shouldn't have to copy any event subscriptions yourself.

Comment: Are you sure about it? Visual Studio's debugger shows that `(((System.MulticastDelegate)((ViewModel.Player.Angles).CollectionChanged)))._invocationCount` equals `2`, but after setting `ViewModel.Player.Angles = deserializedPlayer.Angels`, the debugger shows that `(System.MulticastDelegate)((ViewModel.Player.Angles).CollectionChanged)` is `null`... and yes, I made sure the `OnPropertyChanged("Angles")` is fired

Comment: The binding engine may not update immediately; it may update at a lower `DispatcherPriority`.  But yes, it should pick up the changes.  Try scheduling an empty action on the `Dispatcher` at `Background` priority after updating `Angles`, and set a breakpoint in the action.  Then, when the breakpoint gets hit, check your event handlers.